# input type date format should be 12-mar-23 even if user type 12-03-23

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
      var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
      day = date.getDate();
      month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      year = date.getFullYear();
      alert([day, month, year].join('/'));
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date-input" required />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

In input date, format should be `01-mar-23` even if the user type in  this format `01-03-23`

The required format be **`01-mar-23`**

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get `<input type="date"/>` to use a custom format? If so, this isn't supported by the browser native date pickers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the month name in your date format like this,

```js
const monthNames = [
  "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", 
  "May", "jun", "jul", "aug", 
  "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"
];

(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var d = new Date($('#date-input').val());

    alert([String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'), monthNames[d.getMonth()], d.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)].join('-'));
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date-input" required />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: i have already done this but this is not my requirements( I need if user type 12-03-97 in  input it should display 12-mar-97)

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this by changing the `monthNames` in the whatever format you want and you can change the separator from `/` to `-` and you will get your desired output.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check now. For the dates like `01/03/2023` it will return `01-mar-23`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Format for a date to convert month to string

```
var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
    const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' }).toLowerCase();
    const year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
    const formattedDate = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
    console.log(formattedDate); // Output: "01-mar-23"
```

Answer (score 0):

The date with month in string format you are asking for is not supported in browser native datepickers.

Although, you can achieve the format you need by seperating the day, month and year in 3 `select boxes`, where user can select from the month dropdown, and in that we can pass options according to our requirement like,

- 1st option (January, Jan, jan, 1, etc...)